# inbound loop control varible out of bounds?

Tags: c#

Hello :) I am novice programmer, please help me with the error "Index was out of bounds of the array" I think I am taking into consideration that the value that I am trying to use as my lcv is higher than that of the size of the array. I would really appreciate simplicity in the solution.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("enter a number");
            /**********************************************************/
            string inputString = Console.ReadLine();
            int inputNum;
            int.TryParse(inputString, out inputNum);
            int[] divisorsArray = new int[inputNum -2];
            int[] filteredArray = new int[] { };
            int divisor = 1;
            int yum = 0;
            /**********************************************************/
            for (int i = 0; i < inputNum -2; i++)
            {

                if ( divisor != inputNum && inputNum % divisor == 0)
                    divisorsArray[i] = divisor;                  
                Console.WriteLine(divisorsArray[i]);
                divisor++;
                if (divisorsArray[i]>0)
                {

                    filteredArray[yum] = divisorsArray[i];
                    yum++;
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
```

Comment: `filteredArray` is empty, it has size 0.

Comment: You initialize `filteredArray` to be empty. The size of an array can't be changed, so it's always empty. You then try and access indexes 0, etc. in the empty array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f)

Comment: The duplicate should answer any questions you have :-)

Comment: @John Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Its the line `filteredArray[yum] = divisorsArray[i];` which is not possible because you initialized `fiteredArray` to an empty array. Initilize it as you do with `divisorsArray` and you should do fine.

Comment: I cannot do so in this instance because i don't know how many values will go into fiteredArray.

Comment: Then an array is not the right choice for you. Perhaps use a `List<int>` instead?